# C# SQL Server DataGridView Not Updating

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community just in case. Also I am using a `.mdf` SQL Server database file in VS instead of an external type sql. I wanted to keep everything internal as much as possible for a small program. Now the form loads the gridview appears fine and it works to which I see all of the information. The insert button works as I am able to see the data. Although when click on the refresh button the datagridview does not update, refresh or do nothing. I keeps the same data from when it first loaded. The refresh button does not do anything.

Form 1

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11);  // This works on Form Load
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();    
        form2.Show();                     // This works
    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This button was suppose to be a test button to see if it updates by clicking the Refresh or Update button but it does work
        // I tried many variations like dataGridView1.Update(), dataGridView1.Refresh() 

        // I also tried this below and nothing happens

        // DataGridView.DataSource = null;
        //DataGridView.Rows.Clear();
        //DataGridView.Refresh();

        dataSet11.ContactTable.Clear();
        sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11);

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Form 2

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // This works as I am able to see when the data is inserted to the database
        sqlConnection1.Close();
        sqlCommand1.CommandText = @" insert into dbo.ContactTable (Id, Name, Age)  
                                                           values ('"+txtID.Text.Trim()+"' , '"+txtName.Text.Trim()+"' , '"+txtAge.Text.Trim()+"'  ) ";

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();

        this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you updating dataSet11 after insert operation?

Comment: In the btnRefresh button it clears the dataSet1 and then it trys to load or update it again with sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11).  Is there another peice code that I am missing because I do not get any errors and inserts data properly but when I click the refresh button it does not update what so ever.  The gridview is in form1 and the insert data is in form2.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Thank you for the input on sql parametrized queires.  I will do more research on that.  Although I am still have problems with the refresh button to which it is not updating my gridview even though it does update my database??